# Should I get CE mark on my Arduino project?

Tags: arduino, certification, ce

I just finished my big Arduino project after 2 years. I would like to start selling it, but I am not sure if I need CE certification or not. I used the below components:

- Arduino Nano-oled 0,96"
- keypad
- simple buttons
- TP4056
- 2-5V DC-DC converter
- NRF24L01 2.4 GHz module

I am not sure if I need a CE certificate. Can somebody can help me, please?

Comment: Did you watch the video Dave from the EEVBlog made about the CE markings: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f0uvS80YIGU  Not sure if that will answer your question but its a good watch anyway.

Comment: I live in UK, and unfortunately its recommended here if this necessary.

Comment: Maybe you should try selling it and see who comes to knock on your door. Then you can say oops, sorry. And use the revenue from the first few units to pay for all the certifications.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple answer is: YES.

If you want to sell a product in the European common market, then you need to have it CE certified. Since your product has a radio module in it, then the regulation you should abide to is the RED (Radio Equipment Directive).

You can find more information about the RED [here](https://ec.europa.eu/growth/sectors/electrical-engineering/red-directive_en).

There's links there for the applicable regulations and standards. The RED guide, which can be found [here](https://ec.europa.eu/docsroom/documents/33162/attachments/1/translations/en/renditions/native) can also be useful.

Being very short you'll need to make three kinds of certification tests:

- EMC (EN 301 489-17)
- Safety (EN 60950-1 + EN 50371)
- Radio (EN 300 328)

By the way, due to Brexit, since January this year, if you want to sell in the UK, now you also need the UKCA marking as well.

You have to find a way to perform these tests and provide proof of compliance. You can seek a certification company to help you out with the tests and the necessary documentation.

There are some exceptions depending if you want to sell your product as some kind of development platform. But that's a greyzone, there's no simple answer if want to follow that path. Besides, it's not without necessary due diligence and needed documentation.

Comment: I have just 1 more question. If all parts got CE certification,(which one required)can i sell the product part by part?

I mean i use NRF24L01 module. This module got CE certification. If i use this in my device, i have to do EMC test and RED test. But what happen if i sell parts separately? And customer have to build it together?

Comment: That falls into that greyzone I mentioned of selling the product as a development platform (if you are able to characterize it as such, which is not just saying it is). But, when in doubt keep the following statement in mind:
If you create a product that is made with an assembly of other products, it doesn't matter if all products you use are CE certified, your product, created by the assembly of several parts, is a new product, hence, it needs to be certified.

Comment: In contrast, for instance, for FCC certification, if you use a radio module that is FCC pre-certified, then you can simply get into the market by properly labeling your product stating something along the lines "This product contains a radio module with FCC ID xxxyyyzzz". But, no such thing exists for CE. There's no module certification for CE, if you see a radio module that is CE certified, he is certified as a radio product standalone. As soon as you place it inside a device you built, your product is a new product and needs a separate CE certification on its own.

Comment: Btw please note that LVD also applies below RED, with the voltage limit in LVD scope ignored. What this means in practice is that the various LVD safety standards apply too, when applicable. I believe EN 60950 is actually sorting under LVD rather than RED, though I'd have to look it up.

Comment: Also applicable in this case since there's a keypad/buttons: EN 61000-4-2 for ESD.

Comment: The EN 301 489-17 have the ESD test requirements - section 7.2 (Immunity tests). If you then look further in the reference clause it will point to the normative standard EN 301 489-1, in which you'll find that the applicable standard for the Electrostatic discharge tests, mentioning the conditions, test setup and pass criteria, is then the EN 61000-4-2. But don't mix things up. Everything is interconnected, it's not one way instead of the other.